# How to write a Repository method for a parent entity that returns child entities?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am designing two entities, one called `Country` and one called `CountryDetail`. From the perspective of tables, the `COUNTRY` table will be the parent table, and the `COUNTRY_DETAIL` table will be the child table. In the `COUNTRY` table, there will be a unique attribute called COUNTRY_CODE (note this is not a primary key; the primary key will be a numeric sequence based value). This code will be a foreign key to connect to the child table, and in this child table, each `COUNTRY_CODE` from the parent table will have 3 entries to represent the name of the country in 3 different languages. Following are the entity classes:

**Country.java**

```
    @Entity
    public class Country
    {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "COUNTRY_ID")
        private long id;

        @Column(name="COUNTRY_CODE", nullable = false, unique = true)
        private String countryCode;

        /*public getters*/
    }
```

**CountryDetail.java**

```
  @Entity
    public class CountryDetail
    {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "COUNTRY_DETAIL_ID")
        private long id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="COUNTRY_CODE", referencedColumnName = "COUNTRY_CODE")
        private Country country;
        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String languageCode;
        @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
        private String countryNameInLanguage;

        /*public getters*/
    }
```

My question is, how can I write a custom "findBy..." interface method inside an extension of JpaRepository that is typed to a `Country` that would return me a collection of `CountryDetail` elements that match an input parameter for the `languageCode` attribute of the `CountryDetail` class?

`public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country, Long>`

I know how to do it if the repository was typed to `CountryDetail` instead of `Country`, but I would like to know how to do it going via the parent entity rather than via the child entity directly, even though the input parameter (`languageCode`) exists only in the child entity.

Thank you.

Comment: CountryRepository's query method will return Countries...

Comment: The only way I know to return another type than the Repository type, is by create a custom query and instantiating the object yourself. Something like: `@Query(“SELECT new CountryDetails(c. countryCode) FROM Country c where c.id=:id”)`

Comment: Check this out: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/109816-spring-data-jpa-return-multiple-entities-or-user-defined-object

Comment: @alexbt I ended up writing a custom query after all

Answer (score 3):

It is possible but complicated : Please see an example below :

Parent :

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name="PARENT")
    public class Parent {


        @Id
        @Column(name="PARENT_ID")
        private int parentId;

        @Column(name="PARENT_NAME")
        private String parentName;

       @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
       private Child child;

    }
```

Child :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CHILD")
public class Child {


    @Id
    @Column(name="CHILD_ID")
    private int childId;

    @Column(name="CHILD_NAME")
    private String childName;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Parent parent;
}
```

Define an interface to load child entity from parent repository :

ChildEntity:

```
public interface ChildEntity {

    @Value("#{target.child.childId}")
    int getChildId() ;

    @Value("#{target.child.childName}")
    String getChildName();

}
```

Parent Repository :

```
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Integer> {


    public ChildEntity findByParentName(String parentName);

}
```

Test class:

```
ChildEntity chi=rep.findByParentName("<<NAME>>");
System.out.println(chi.getChildId()+" "+chi.getChildName());
```

Output:

```
CHILD ID 1000 CHILD NAME child1
```

Comment: I think this will be helpful for others, but in my case, I was having lots of issue with one to many associations (no one to one associations), so I ended up using a custom query instead.